# False proof that $ρe^{iθ} = ρ$ and so complex numbers do not exist?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification, exponentiation, fake-proofs

My professor showed the following false proof, which showed that complex numbers do not exist. We were told to find the point where an incorrect step was taken, but I could not find it. Here is the proof: (Complex numbers are of the form $\rho e^{i\theta}$, so the proof begins there) $$\large\rho e^{i\theta} = \rho e^{\frac{2 \pi i \theta}{2\pi}} = \rho (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = \rho (1)^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = \rho$$
$$Note: e^{i\pi} = -1, e^{2\pi i} = (-1)^2 = 1$$
Since we started with the general form of a complex number and simplified it to a real number (namely, $\rho$), the proof can claim that only real numbers exist and complex numbers do not. My suspicion is that the error occurs in step $4$ to $5$ , but I am not sure if that really is the case.

Comment: $e^{2\pi i+2\pi k i}=1$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for starters. Also, what is $\left(e^{z}\right)^w$ with $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The special case $\theta=\pi$ is $-1=(-1)^{2/2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$, so negative numbers do not exist either.

Comment: you first find the total exponent then perform potentiation.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The error lies in assuming that $(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}):e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$.

It's worse than wrong; it doesn't make sense. The reason why it doesn't make sense is because $e^a$ can be an arbitrary complex number (except that it can't be $0$). And what is $z^w$, where $z,w\in\mathbb C$? A reasonable definition is that it means $e^{w\log z}$, where $\log z$ is *a* logarithm of $z$. Problem: every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms: if a number $\omega$ is a logarithm, then every number of the form $\omega+2k\pi i$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$) is also a logarithm.

Comment: I think it’s worth explaining to OP why it makes no sense. When your background is real, it’s a completely natural thing to expect or assume must be okay.

Comment: I agree with Randall. Would you be able to explain why this is the case? So far most of what I have dealt with is in the set of real numbers.

Comment: @Randall You are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @MadhavNakar What do you think now?

Comment: I understand the reasoning now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @BCLC He is saying the reverse. Your first statement is wrong, your second is right.

Comment: @eranreches Thanks. Pressed enter while in rush. Edit: $$\large \rho e^{\frac{i\theta*2\pi}{2\pi}} = \rho (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} \tag{1}$$ $$\large \rho (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = \rho (1)^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} \tag{2}$$ I guess (1) is wrong but (2) is right. If so why? If not what then? I think (2) is wrong because of what Antinous pointed out

Comment: Strictly speaking he is only assuming $b \in \mathbb R$, and $a^b$ is defined when $a \in \mathbb C$ and $b \in \mathbb R$.  So this answer isn't correct is it?

Comment: While the opening sentence of this answer is correct, the OP only involves a case of $(e^a)^b$ where $e^a$ is (positive) **real** (more precisely, it is $1$), so the second paragraph going on about the (very real, no pun intended) difficulties of defining  $z^w$ when $z$ is not real (or I would add, when it is real but negative) do not really pertain to the original question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The second part of my answer was ment to explain why the equality $(e^z)^w=e^{zw}$ makes no sense in general.

Answer (score 7):

Because for complex numbers, $e^{zc}\ne(e^z)^c$ for $z,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Does this imply that only one-to-one functions have this property?

Comment: $f(z)=1$ is also multiplicative.

Comment: Sorry, failure of this identity and the exponential function not being injective are entirely different matters. Maybe exponential function not being injective is a reason that defining $(e^z)^c$ is problematic and cannot be done so as to have this identity, but "in other words" is just not right.