# Euler's identity confusion: $e^{\pi} = e^{-\pi}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

We know from Euler's identity that $$e^{\pi i} = -1.$$ 
So that means $$(e^{\pi i})^{-i} = e^{\pi} = (-1)^{-i} = ((-1)^{-1})^{i} = (-1)^{i}.$$
But also we have 
$$ (-1)^{i} =( e^{\pi i})^{i} = e^{-\pi}$$
But how can this be, since $e^{\pi} \neq e^{-\pi}$?

Comment: Well, this is exactly the reason why $z\to z^i$ (which first of all has to be defined of course) is not a function in general. Indeed, it returns infinitely many different values. This is why we have to define branches of logarithm to turn this into a function.

Comment: You can check the top answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582046/false-proof-that-%cf%81ei%ce%b8-%cf%81-and-so-complex-numbers-do-not-exist/2582053#2582053), it addresses the same issue

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10/3219039#3219039)

Comment: So many errors in your fake proof. I suppose you actually don't realize that you haven't been taught properly what exponentiation really is. Please read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085631/21820) very carefully, and then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2861087/21820). If you have started learning basic real analysis, then you should also read through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790356/21820), but if you are only at high-school level then just make sure you know that every law applies **only under certain conditions**, and you must know exactly what those are.

Comment: By the way, I myself was taught improperly too, and also did such nonsense with exponentiation when I was young. It should not be surprising that every mathematics student who is taught improperly is likely to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about $(-1)^{-i} = (-1)^i$, but it doesn't mean $e^{\pi} = e^{-\pi}$.
Please consider the following case as an analogy:
$$
(-2)^2 = 4 = (+2)^2,
$$
but it does not mean $-2 = +2$.
In essence, your equations state
$$
(e^{-\pi})^i = (e^{\pi})^i,
$$
but it does not imply $e^{-\pi} = e^{\pi}$.