# Fake proof that $\sqrt{i} = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

$\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so $X^2 - i \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ has two roots counting multiplicities. Geometrically, $e^{i\theta_1}$ and $e^{i \theta_2}$ must be roots if we set $\theta_1 = \pi/4$ and $\theta_2 = 5 \pi / 4$. But:

$$\begin{align*}
i^{1/2} &= i^{4/8} \tag{1} \\
&= (i^4)^{1/8} \tag{2} \\
&= (1)^{1/8} \tag{3} \\
&= \langle e^{i \pi/4} \rangle \tag{4}
\end{align*}$$
(the last line is the subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}, \times)$ generated by $e^{i \pi/4}$. Which step is wrong and why? Do complex numbers not satisfy $z^{\alpha \cdot \beta} = (z^\alpha)^\beta$?

Comment: Yes, they don't satisfy the last statement - in general.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10); fractional powers are not uniquely defined for negative and imaginary numbers, and the "general rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m×n
}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers.

Comment: It is actually quite difficult to define $z^w$ for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. For example, how would you interpret $i^i$?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582046/false-proof-that-%cf%81ei%ce%b8-%cf%81-and-so-complex-numbers-do-not-exist) thread might be of use to you.