# $e^{i2\pi a}=1$ or $e^{i2\pi a}=\cos(2\pi a)+i\sin(2\pi a)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, complex-integration, complete-spaces

Since $e^{i2\pi a}=(e^{i2\pi})^a=(1)^a=1$ but $e^{i2\pi a}=\cos(2\pi a)+i\sin(2\pi a)\neq1$, why is that?

Comment: Please use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) to search if your question exists here before asking.

Comment: What makes you think that complex exponentiation satisfies $(z^a)^b= z^{ab}$?

Comment: $\sin (2\pi a)=0$ and $\cos (2\pi a)=1$, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @sirous But the OP says that it should work for any $a$...

Comment: This question and its answers are more precise: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2582046/305862